# Environment values in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi all I  want to ask if Ruby has an environment values that i can store a variable in it and use it anywhere in my test , just like QTP Environment.value = "SomeValue"

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are stored in the `ENV`constant, and it can be accessed like an `Hash`

e.g

```
ENV["PS1"]
=> "\\u@\\h:\\w (\\t)$ "
```

Environment variables are useful in storing configurations

so:

```
ENV["QTP"] = "Some value"
```

would make `ENV["QTP"]` an environment variable that can be accessed throughout the lifespan of your application (you can tune this based on what environment you are in `test`, `development` or `production`)

So you can store your configuration in shell variables before running your ruby application, with a `bar.rb` containing:

```
puts ENV["QTP"]
```

Running your ruby file as below:

```
QTP=foo ruby bar.rb
```

Would print "foo" to your console

alternatively you can store values in a Constant, and it "should" remain same throughout the life span of your app

Answer (score 0):

If it's for your test and you are not concern by thread safety you can use a global variable or a constant.

```
$global_var = "SomeValue"
CONSTANT = "SomeValue"
```

The `CONSTANT` is not supposed to be modified, and the `$global_var` can be modified

If you are concerned by Threads you can use Thread variable

```
Thread.current[:your_var_name] = "SomeValue"
```

Each Thread have a different value for `Thread.current[:your_var_name]`

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply but what do you mean about THREAD ? i have a main class that i want to save many values returned from excel sheet to use it in other classes ... since my test is data driven

Comment: If you don't know about Thread, then you are not concern by that part of the answer and you can go for a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

[Environment Variables](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) are exactly that -- variables stored in your app's *environment*

The environment of your app is the OS / server your app is running on, meaning if you want to store variables for use in your app, you'll have to set them up at the OS level

---

[**Heroku**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

The best example of ENV variables in Rails on Heroku:

```
heroku config:set YOUR_VAR=your_value
```

---

**Figaro**

I would highly recommend looking at the [`Figaro` gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)

This emulates the ENV variables in development, and allows you to push them to your production environment very easily

It's highly recommended you keep your ENV data consistent across all your environments, which is what Figaro is very good at :)